# Wrap incoming jax-rs POST json message body in a parent object

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

I have a need to parse some json that comes to an endpoint of mine.  **I cannot change the incoming json**, it is sent by a 3rd party.  The json in the request body is technically valid but it has no parent element so I can't seem to parse it.  Ideally I'd be able to wrap the whole thing in an object, so basically, how can I actually add the "wrapper" object:

```
{
  "wrapper": {
    {
      "value1": 1,
      "value2": 2,
      "value3": 3
    }
  }
}
```

if the original was:

```
{
  "value1": 1,
  "value2": 2,
  "value3": 3
}
```

With that I could make a model and use xml annotation as I have elsewhere in the project, something like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "wrapper")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class WrapperObject {

    @XmlElement(name = "value1")
    private int value1;
    @XmlElement(name = "value2")
    private int value2;
    @XmlElement(name = "value3")
    private int value3;
}
```

And then I could have the rest method be

```
@POST
@Path("/cloud")
@Override
public Response handleResponse(WrapperObject wrapper) throws Exception {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your question is an answer, my answer will be a question. What do you ask? p.s. your idea and code look fine. When a project is spread between Front end and Back end teams they should always have a CONTRACT about the data transfer objects so parsing is possible for the both sides.

Comment: My question has an example of what I would like to see, not how to make that happen.  I would like to be able to parse the wrapper object directly in the rest method

Comment: You must build Gson or jackson object withthat wrapper class

Comment: Put your wrapper object as @requestparam of your rest service

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: So it is normal you can't change the incoming json structure

Comment: You just have to know what to expect from the incoming requests